# How to animate ng-repeat items relative to click events causing the change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm trying to animate a user selecting items from different sets of items.
The item should animate from the clicked set to it's new position in list of selected items.

In the below demo, consider the pink boxes as available items and the bordered box as the list of selected items (blue boxes). User can select an item by clicking on either of the pink boxes:

```js
angular.module('test', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
    $scope.purchased = [{}];
    $scope.purchase = function(dir) {
      $scope.direction = dir
      $scope.purchased.push($scope.products.pop());
    };
  })
  .directive('testDir', function($animate) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $animate.on('enter', element, function(element, phase) {
          $target = scope.direction == 'left' ? $('.stock:first') : $('.stock:last');
          element.position({
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            of: $target,
            using: function(pos, data) {
              $(this).css(pos);
              $(this).animate({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.stock {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: hotpink;
}
.stock.right {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.product {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.purchased {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 2px dotted;
}
.purchased .product {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div class="stock" ng-click="purchase('left')"></div>
  <div class="stock right" ng-click="purchase('right')"></div>
  <div class="purchased clearfix">
    <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in purchased" data-test-dir>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Well, it kind of works - but I'm using jQuery-ui to find out the starting position (The position of pink boxes will wary in a responsive design) and jquery animate method to animate the element.

Also I have to store the clicked direction in scope and I'm setting both the initial position and animating to end position in the `enter` event listener.

I have been reading and experimenting a lot with  built in animation hooks in angular, but couldn't figure out a proper way to animate elements from relative/dynamic positions.

Is there a better way to achieve the same user experience in angular js way..?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve same behavior without using any jquery ui?

Comment: @kiran Using jQuery UI to find position is fine. I thought there will be a better way to structure this in angular, like without having to store clicked directions in controller scope... I also don't think doing the whole thing in `$animate.on('enter'` is the right way

Comment: It might be beneficial to check out ng-animate-ref as it is meant for animating an element across application areas like you want. I think it is typically meant for a 1-to-1 relationship, so if your element can spawn multiple instances like your demo, then you might need to hook the end of the animation and pull the ref out once complete so that the next iteration doesn't animate multiple elements. Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: @ColtMcCormack That only works while  transitioning between views...

Comment: It seems fine, you just might want to attach the Model to the Div so that way you can just loop over purchases and then you will have the Model and datasets therein to walk and process accordingly.

Comment: Why are you using $animate.on('enter') at all?  Why not just kick off the animation directly in the link function?

Comment: @JoeEnzminger good question. If I do that, the products already in purchased list (consider as data got from rest API or something) will fly across screen even though user didn't interact at all. I need to somehow tie up the  animation and click event happening outside directive. (Also In the actual application The directive is on `.purchased` div, the product thingies don't have any functionality so they are simple elements with no directive on them.)

Comment: I see.  With it, unfortunately, you get a flicker because it takes one digest from when the element is added to the list to when the animation starts.  Pretty interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

if I've understood your question correctly(tell me if not); i think one way to handle the problem, goes like this:

while assuming the size(width) of your products to be constant -set to 50px or something- ; you can set the pink elements' position to absolute; then use ng-repeat for pink elements, with a brief ng-style attribute inside the html like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products" ng-style="{'left': $index*50 + 'px'}" ng-click="add-to-purchased($index)"></div>
```

and about the purchased products: instead of using ng-repeat on the "purchased" array, inside "add-to-purchased" function, after pushing the product to the "purchased" array, you can simply animate the product to the "top: 'the height distance to the bordered element'" and "left" equal to {$scope.purchased.length*50 + 'px'}. then add a class using ng-class (with a toggle) for coloring and other css stuff... (you can also consider transition for color changes. as you probably know)

i also think that you can handle different heights and tops problem(in case that the number of products becomes more than one line's capacity) with an ng-class which adds classes with new "top" values based on: ($index > some-number), and another ng-class for the upper element(the element that's on top of the bordered element), changing it's height ...

i hope this was helpful

---

**Update:**

unfortunately i hadn't understood the question well. but looking at the problem now, i think there is a way of doing this more dynamically.

inside the `$scope.purchase` function, you can message your directive with `$broadcast` and passing the clicked element like this (for any element in stock, either it's created with ng-repeat or not):

```
<div class="stock" ng-click="purchase($event)"></div>
```

and:

```
$scope.purchase = function(event) {
  $scope.purchased.push($scope.products.pop());
  $scope.$broadcast('purchaseHappened', event.target);
};
```

and inside your directive, put the event listener:

```
scope.$on('purchaseHappened', function(event, target) {
     //catch target in here, and then use it's position to animate the new elements...
})
```

i think you can also use `target.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the element's position, relative to the viewport (`.top` , `.left` ,...) instead of jquery-ui's `.position` if you want...

is it closer to the solution?

Comment: You missed many things in question. 1) This is a responsive design, so nothing is constant 2) Not using ng-repeat is not an option (other external directives like `ui-sortable` rely on it), that's why I specifically asked "How to animate ng-repeat items". If everything was constant I could simply define the pixel positions in css classes and switch them
3) detecting the clicked mouse position

Comment: *"you can simply animate the product to the "top: 'the height distance to the bordered element'" and "left" equal to {$scope.purchased.length*50 + 'px'}"* - how to do this the angular way, while using `ng-repeat` and responsive design is the question. Assume we can find the current position of stock and products using jquery ui `position()` method, but for that we should first detect the clicked stock. and then how to use these dynamic information for animation in angular ng-repeat, in a better way than how I already did all this is what I'm asking

Comment: What I already have works better than your suggestion: 1) Doesn't assume anything is constant 2) detects the clicked position (by storing it in  controller scope which I think is a poor way of doing it) 3)works with ng-repeat. I thought there is a better way to do this in angular so I'll ask the angular experts and learn something new

Comment: i think i just understood your question! so let me ask another detail. is the stock of products always in this form of two elements, or that also is for the sake of example?
i mean in real codes, are you gonna use ng-repeat for them too? cause i thought of another way for the problem.

Comment: In my specific case it's just two like this. But  general solution might help someone else in future

Comment: i've updated the answer, please check it and let me know if i'm getting closer

Answer (score 0):

This solution is an improvement in that it eliminates the need to add information to the scope in the Purchase function and it avoids mixing model data and UI details by using a "source" directive and storing origin information in a controller property.  The example is simplified and can of course be improved. The key point is that the data required to manage the process is never exposed via the scope.

If the target element is subject to being removed from the DOM (i.e it's part of an ng-repeat, then this solution would have to be modified slightly to calculate and store the animation start positions as part of the monitor.click handler rather than store the target element itself.

The method of animation seems to me to be arbitrary.  This example uses the OP's jqueryUI animation method, but it would work just as well with css transitions or using $animate.

A full example is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/OH2Fdpoce5ploU25S72i?p=preview)

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{},{}];
  $scope.purchased = [{}];
  $scope.Purchase = function() {
    $scope.purchased.push({});
  };
})
.directive('source', function(){
  return {
    controller: function($scope) {
    }
  };
})
.directive('originator', function(){
  return{
    require: '^source',
    priority: 1,
    link:{
      pre: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
        element.on('click', function(evt){
          ctrl.target = evt.target;    
        });
      } 
    }
  };
})
.directive('sink', function(){
  return {
    require: '^source',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
      var target = ctrl.target;
      if(target){
        var $target = $(target);
        //animate from target to current position
        element.position({
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            of: $target,
            using: function(pos, data) {
              $(this).css(pos);
              $(this).animate({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
              });
            }
          });
        ctrl.target = undefined;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: The difference I see is that eventually the property is being added to controller itself rather than `$scope` along with extra directives, event handlers etc... This looks like a complexified form of what I have... Anyway i'm giving this the bounty for the time and effort put :)