# position() in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css-position

I am new to jquery UI. I was reading position() docs of jquery UI. It includes details about **'of', 'at'** and **'my'** arguments.

I am clear about 'of' argument, But I am still confused about '**at**' and '**my**' arguments.

As per my understanding, I believe only one of them is required. *Can you let me know why both of them are required?*

Moreover, It also tells about target element and positioned element. *Can you let me know, what does they point to, by taking some good example ?*

Sorry for such a simple question and bad english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It also tells about target element and positioned element. Can you let me know, what does they point to

---

> I am clear about 'of' argument

Two of your statements are in conflict here. If you are clear about `of` argument, you should know what is target element already.

Positioned element is the element you want to position. Let's call it `A`.

target element is the element relative to which you want to position `A`.

`of` is used to specify your target element.

`my` and `at` are used to specify how you want to position these. `my` specifies the positioning of `A`, and `at` specify how it should be positioned relative to target.

For example `my: 'top left'` `at:'bottom right'` means you want top put the top left corner of `A` at the bottom right corner of target element

---

> Can you let me know why both of them are required?

They are not *required*. The docs clearly says that their default value is "center". You don't need to specify them if you don't want to change the defaults

---

Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34875771/2333214) that I asked few days back with a snippet using positioning where I say I want to position the center of `A` at the center of target.

Comment: Can you let me know the differences between left and top-left, right and top-right, bottom and bottom-left and so on ?

Comment: @user2393267 consider the element as a square. It'll have 2 corners on top and 2 on bottom. top left mean select the one on left side among the 2 corners in top. bottom right means select the right corner among the 2 corners at bottom and so on...

Comment: I have something like this my: 'top+15', at: 'right-180', can you help me out, how this will be positioned,i.e., how (x, y) coordinates will be calculated ?

Comment: @user2393267  `my: 'top+15', at: 'right-180'`,  is equivalent to `my: 'center top+15' , at: 'right-180 center', `  the point at the center of your elements x axis and 15px above its top on y axis will be positioned at the point 180px backwards from the right side on x axis and center on y axis of the target.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

**I believe only one of them is required. Can you let me know why both of them are required?**
No Both are not same, `at` is positioned from parent and `my` is positioned from current position by `my` option.

**Can you let me know, what does they point to, by taking some good example ?**
They are pointing to position offset properties (left, right, top and bottom)

**my (default: "center")**
*Type: String*
Defines which position on the element being positioned to align with the target element: "horizontal vertical" alignment.

A single value such as "right" will be normalized to "right center", "top" will be normalized to "center top" (following CSS convention). Acceptable horizontal values: "left", "center", "right".

Acceptable vertical values: "top", "center", "bottom". Example: "left top" or "center center". Each dimension can also contain offsets, in pixels or percent, e.g., "right+10 top-25%". Percentage offsets are relative to the element being positioned.

**at (default: "center")**
*Type: String*
Defines which position on the target element to align the positioned element against: "horizontal vertical" alignment. See the my option for full details on possible values. Percentage offsets are relative to the target element.

Refer for more information: 
http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: Can you please add clarification for statement "at is positioned from parent and my is positioned from current position by my option." ? Moreover, Please don't write whichever it's written in jquery ui docs. If I were able to understand it, then I might not have asked this question.

Comment: That was by mistake due to internet connectivity issue !

Comment: I have something like this my: 'top+15', at: 'right-180', can you help me out, how this will be positioned,i.e., how (x, y) coordinates will be calculated ?